# React App on Vite, audio assets not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I'm building the Day1 project of JavaScript 30, using React and Vite.

When I load the page, the console throws errors saying

`localhost:5173/assets/Sounds/tink.wav 404 (Not Found)`

I move the sound files under the public folder, and use "/Sounds/XXX.wav" to refer to them, but the error persists.

So I move the sound files back to src/assets folder, not knowing what to do with the paths...

Here's my code:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css'
import Key from "./Keys/Key"

function App() {
  const soundPath = "../assets/Sounds";

  function playSound(keyCode) {
    let soundName = '';
    switch (keyCode) {
      case 65:
        soundName = 'clap';
        break;
      case 83:
        soundName = 'hihat';
        break;
      case 68:
        soundName = 'kick';
        break;
      case 70:
        soundName = 'openhat';
        break;
      case 71:
        soundName = 'boom';
        break;
      case 72:
        soundName = 'ride';
        break;
      case 74:
        soundName = 'snare';
        break;
      case 75:
        soundName = 'tom';
        break;
      case 76:
        soundName = 'tink';
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
    const audio = new Audio(`${soundPath}/${soundName}.wav`);
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
  }
  

  function handleKeyDown(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    const audioElement = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${event.keyCode}"]`);
    if (audioElement) {
      playSound(event.keyCode);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="keys">
        <Key dataKey="65" kbdName="A" soundName="clap" />
        <Key dataKey="83" kbdName="S" soundName="hihat" />
        <Key dataKey="68" kbdName="D" soundName="kick" />
        <Key dataKey="70" kbdName="F" soundName="openhat" />
        <Key dataKey="71" kbdName="G" soundName="boom" />
        <Key dataKey="72" kbdName="H" soundName="ride" />
        <Key dataKey="74" kbdName="J" soundName="snare" />
        <Key dataKey="75" kbdName="K" soundName="tom" />
        <Key dataKey="76" kbdName="L" soundName="tink" />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

As for the Key Component:

```
import classes from "./Key.module.css"
import Sound from "../Audio/Sound";
const Key = props => {
    const src= `../../assets/Sounds/${props.soundName}.wav`
    return (
    <div data-key={props.dataKey} className={classes.key}>
        <kbd>{props.kbdName}</kbd>
        <span className={classes.sound}>{props.soundName}</span>
        <Sound data-key={props.dataKey} src={src}/>
    </div>
    );
}

export default Key;
```

Sound.jsx(I tried to avoid the name Audio, in fear of clashing with HTML Audio object):

```
const Sound = props => {
    return (
    <audio data-key={props.dataKey} src={props.src}></audio>
    );
}
export default Sound;
```

Comment: Why not check the [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html)?

Comment: I did put the Sounds folder under public directory, and referred to them using absolute path like "/Sounds/XXX.wav" and it didn't work.

Comment: *didn't work* can be due to many reasons. Either you did it wrong, since you havn't shown that attempt. Or you did it right and it doesn't work for you even though that's the documented and well tested way to do it that works for other people that use vite. I'm going to guess you did some mistake somewhere. But if all you are going to say is "I tried, it didn't work", how can we help you?